# angular bootstrap typeahead + something like ng-enter

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I've got an input field with a typeahead (which is working correctly).
Now what I want (and what's not working) is to execute another call when the user writes something into the typeahead text-field and then presses the enter key and there is -no- typeahead catching. (In this case I want to display an error message).

How can this be achieved ? (The following code is my example, though the line with 'ng-enter' doesn't work like this.

```
<input
   type="text"
   ng-model="vm.activeOrder"
   ng-enter="console.log('show error message maybe')"
   typeahead-on-select="vm.selectOrderInTypeAhead($item, $model, $label)"
   typeahead="order as order.order_number for order in vm.get OrdersForTypeAhead($viewValue)"
  class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `ng-enter directive`(something like this one):

```
app.directive('ngEnter', function ($window) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $window.alert('error');
                });
            }
        });
    };
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wr65o375/).